# Generating random change in photon frequency $\Delta \nu$ from angle-averaged isotropic redistribution function

Tags: astrophysics, computational-physics, probability, simulations, randomness

I am implementing the Monte Carlo Simulation Code for the case of photons being scattered by electrons. The paper I'm referring ([Hillier 1991](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1991A%26A...247..455H), Appendix B) suggests that after each scattering, the change in frequency of the photon, $\Delta \nu$, is randomly generated from the angle-averaged isotropic redistribution function given by $$ R(\nu,\nu^{'})=w^{-1} \mathit{ierfc}|(\nu^{'}-\nu)/2w|$$ where $w$ is known and $$ \mathit{ierfc}(x)= \pi^{-1/2} e^{-x^{2}}- x \thinspace \mathit{erfc(x)}$$

How does one generate a random $\Delta \nu$ from this redistribution function?

Comment: I think you have to talk to the author of the paper to get a handle on the error functions and their  integrals.

Answer (score 0):

If you can *plot* the function with the delta(ν)  , you can use it to generate random delta(ν) to fit the function. I suppose that  you know what erfc(ν)  is?

Comment: I can plot the redistribution function and I'm familiar with erfc function. But how does one get a "random" $\Delta \nu$ from this plot?

Comment: Throw random delta( ν) with a weight of this curve, like integrating it with Monte Carlo

Comment: Isn't this going to give the CDF of $\Delta \nu$?